# Создать динамический SQL запрос

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Мне надо построить динамический `SQL-запрос`, по которому будет осуществляться поиск объектов в базе данных. Поиск должен производится по фильтру, в котором несколько параметров для поиска. У меня есть готовые таблицы, класс `Filter`с конструкторами и геттерами. Вот класс `DAO`с методами поиска и составления запроса:

```
public class RoomDAO extends GeneralDAO<Room> {

    private static final String SQL_GET_ROOM_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM ROOM WHERE ID = :idParam";
    private static final String NATIVE_SQL_GET_ROOMS_BY_FILTER = "SELECT * FROM ROOM r, HOTEL h WHERE h.ID = r.ID_HOTEL AND BREAKFAST_INCLUDED = :brParam AND PETS_ALLOWED = :petParam";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<Room> findRooms(Filter filter){

        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()){

            NativeQuery<Room> roomQuery = session.createNativeQuery(createQuery(filter));
            roomQuery.setParameter("brParam", filter.isBreakfastIncluded());
            roomQuery.setParameter("petParam", filter.isPetsAllowed());
            roomQuery.list();

            return (Collection<Room>) roomQuery;
        }
    }

    public String createQuery(Filter filter){

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append(NATIVE_SQL_GET_ROOMS_BY_FILTER);

        if (filter.getNumberOfGuests() != 0)
            stringBuilder.append(" AND r.NUMBER_OF_GUESTS = ").append(filter.getNumberOfGuests());

        if (filter.getPrice() != 0)
            stringBuilder.append(" AND r.PRICE = ").append(filter.getPrice());

        if (filter.getDateAvailableFrom() != null)
            stringBuilder.append(" AND r.DATE_AVAILABLE_FROM = ").append(filter.getDateAvailableFrom());

        if (filter.getCountry() != null)
            stringBuilder.append(" AND h.COUNTRY = '").append(filter.getCountry()).append("'");

        if (filter.getCity() != null)
            stringBuilder.append(" AND h.CITY = '").append(filter.getCity()).append("'");

        return String.valueOf(stringBuilder);
    }
}
```

И вот какая падает ошибка при проверке работы метода поиска:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=64968:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\IdeaProjects\javajdbcgrom\target\classes;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0\ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.16.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.0\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Skorodielov\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar" hibernate_dz.dz_lesson4.demo.RoomDemo
июн 01, 2018 4:01:08 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
июн 01, 2018 4:01:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
июн 01, 2018 4:01:08 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
июн 01, 2018 4:01:08 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
июн 01, 2018 4:01:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
июн 01, 2018 4:01:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@gromcode-lesson.cjqbbseqr63c.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:ORCL]
июн 01, 2018 4:01:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=main, password=****}
июн 01, 2018 4:01:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
июн 01, 2018 4:01:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
июн 01, 2018 4:01:09 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM ROOM r, HOTEL h WHERE h.ID = r.ID_HOTEL AND BREAKFAST_INCLUDED = ? AND PETS_ALLOWED = ? AND r.PRICE = 175.0
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
    at hibernate_dz.dz_lesson4.dao.RoomDAO.findRooms(RoomDAO.java:28)
    at hibernate_dz.dz_lesson4.demo.RoomDemo.main(RoomDemo.java:51)
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.validateAliases(CustomLoader.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:2214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2170)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2161)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Пробовал делать запрос и без псевдонимов таблиц, ошибка такая же падает. Подскажите, как я могу это исправить в этом варианте ?

Структура таблиц `HOTEL` и `ROOM`:

```
CREATE TABLE HOTEL(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
CITY NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
STREET NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ROOM(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ID_HOTEL NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT ROOM_FK FOREIGN KEY(ID_HOTEL)REFERENCES HOTEL(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL,
NUMBER_OF_GUESTS NUMBER NOT NULL,
PRICE NUMBER(*, 2) NOT NULL,
BREAKFAST_INCLUDED NUMBER CHECK (BREAKFAST_INCLUDED = 1 OR BREAKFAST_INCLUDED = 0),
PETS_ALLOWED NUMBER CHECK (PETS_ALLOWED = 1 OR PETS_ALLOWED = 0),
DATE_AVAILABLE_FROM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас в обоих таблицах есть поле `ID` и поскольку вы используете `*` для имен полей, то поле `ID` попадает два раза в результат. В связи с чем hibernate ругается на дублирование алиаса.

Чтобы это исправить надо переименовать алиасы для двух таблиц, которые вы джойните, чтобы небыло совпадений.

Comment: Roman C, они по разному названы  `h.ID = r.ID_HOTEL` ... что надо поменять ?

Comment: нужно поменять алиасы, я вроде так и написал в своем ответе

Comment: Roman C, можете конкретней указать, что надо поменять ? Алиас это псевдоним таблицы, насколько я понимаю и они разные `r` и `h`, так же названия колонок разные. В таблице `ROOM` колонка `ID_HOTEL` , в таблице `HOTEL` колонка `ID`. Что надо поменять, чтобы не дублировался `ID` ?

Comment: нет не могу, ты недостаточно полно задал вопрос и в нем нехватает необходимой информации.  Распечатай и добавь структуру таблиц в вопрос.

Comment: Roman C, структуру таблиц добавил ... а может вместо `*` перечислить названия колонок в таблицах или не поможет ?

Comment: Roman C, понял кажется в чём дело... в таблицах колонки с одинаковым названием `ID`... надо переименовать название одной из этих двух колонок... спасибо за помощь